# How do foreach loops work in C#?

Tags: c#, foreach

Which types of classes can use `foreach` loops?

Comment: You may want to choose a different accepted answer, since the one you selected isn't really representative of the correct answer.

Answer (score 167):

Actually, **strictly** speaking, all you need to use `foreach` is a public `GetEnumerator()` method that returns something with a `bool MoveNext()` method and a `? Current {get;}` property. However, the most **common** meaning of this is "something that implements `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>`, returning an `IEnumerator`/`IEnumerator<T>`.

By implication, this includes anything that implements `ICollection`/`ICollection<T>`, such as anything like `Collection<T>`, `List<T>`, arrays (`T[]`), etc. So any standard "collection of data" will generally support `foreach`.

For proof of the first point, the following works just fine:

```
using System;
class Foo {
    public int Current { get; private set; }
    private int step;
    public bool MoveNext() {
        if (step >= 5) return false;
        Current = step++;
        return true;
    }
}
class Bar {
    public Foo GetEnumerator() { return new Foo(); }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        foreach (int item in bar) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**How does it work?**

A foreach loop like `foreach(int i in obj) {...}` kinda equates to:

```
var tmp = obj.GetEnumerator();
int i; // up to C# 4.0
while(tmp.MoveNext()) {
    int i; // C# 5.0
    i = tmp.Current;
    {...} // your code
}
```

However, there are variations. For example, if the enumerator (tmp) supports `IDisposable`, it is used too (similar to `using`).

**Note the difference** in the placement of the declaration "`int i`" *inside* (C# 5.0) vs. *outside* (up C# 4.0) the loop. It's important if you use `i` in an anonymous method/lambda inside your code-block. But that is another story ;-p

Comment: +1 for going in depth.  I normally don't go that in depth for a question that may be a 'beginner' question since it would seem overwhelming to the new programmer.

Comment: True, Gortok - so I followed up with the stuff about lists/arrays/etc.

Comment: Would be good to mention the implicit runtime casting to the loop variable - can produce type incompatibility exceptions.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line inside the `while` loop be `i = tmp.Current;`?

Comment: Don't forget: When using a array with foreach the compiler creates a simple `for-loop`( You can see this when working with IL ).

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Yes, the location of "i" is important to what happens with lambdas, but you got it wrong. "i" is placed **inside** the loop. The language spec says `The placement of v inside the while loop is important for how it is captured by any anonymous function occurring in the embedded-statement.` (with "v" being your "i"). It even gives an example.

Comment: @PaulGroke no, I didn't "get it wrong". The specification **changed** in C# 5 - i.e. pretty recently. This answer was Dec '08. Prior to C# 5, the placement was semantically **outside** the `while` - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12112959

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that! I just checked the current spec, and assumed ... Well, thanks for the clarification! :-)

Comment: @Paul well, thanks for prompting me to tweak the answer slightly to account for the change

Comment: @Marc Gravell: OK, cool! I edited the post to make it more clear - at least to me. After all the placement isn't only important in C# 5.0, it's always important, only that it changed. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Here is a good auricle with examples of how things work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Answer (score 7):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.80).aspx):

> The `foreach` statement repeats a group
>   of embedded statements for each
>   element in **an array or an object
>   collection**. The `foreach` statement is
>   used to iterate through the collection
>   to get the desired information, but
>   should not be used to change the
>   contents of the collection to avoid
>   unpredictable side effects. (emphasis mine)

So, if you have an array, you could use the foreach statement to iterate through the array, like so:

```
 int[] fibarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
    foreach (int i in fibarray)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

You could also use it to iterate through a `List<T>` collection, like so:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (string item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: oddly enough, according to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9(VS.80).aspx), objects types don't need to implement IEnumerable. Any type that defines GetEnumerator, MoveNext, Reset and Current the correct way will work. Weird, huh?

Comment: Neat. I didn't know that. :-)

Comment: Small clarification to the above comment, you do not need the Reset method.

Answer (score 4):

According to the blog post *[Duck Notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kcwalina/duck-notation)*, duck typing is used.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the docs:  [Main article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.71).aspx) [With Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288254(VS.71).aspx) [With Collection Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257(VS.71).aspx)

It's important to note that "The type of the collection element must be convertible to the identifier type".  This sometimes cannot be checked at compile time and can generate a runtime exception if the instance type is not assignable to the reference type.

This will generate a runtime exception if there is an non-Apple in the fruit basket, such as an orange.

```
List<Fruit> fruitBasket = new List<Fruit>() { new Apple(), new Orange() };
foreach(Apple a in fruitBasket)
```

This safely filters the list to only the Apples using [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
foreach(Apple a in fruitBasket.OfType<Apple>() )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IList<ListItem> illi = new List<ListItem>();
ListItem li = null;

foreach (HroCategory value in listddlsubcategory)
{
    listddlsubcategoryext = server.getObjectListByColumn(typeof(HroCategory), "Parentid", value.Id);
    li = new ListItem();
    li.Text = value.Description;
    li.Value = value.Id.ToString();
    illi.Add(li);
    IList<ListItem> newilli = new List<ListItem>();
    newilli = SubCatagoryFunction(listddlsubcategoryext, "-->");
    foreach (ListItem c in newilli)
    {
        illi.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Useful info regarding this subject can be found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) too. Taking the essence from that article:

The foreach keyword enumerates a collection, executing the embedded statement once for each element in the collection:

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

The compiler translates the foreach loop shown in the above example into something similar to this construct:

```
IEnumerator<int> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var item = enumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this...

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(5);
        numbers.Add(15);
        numbers.Add(25);
        numbers.Add(35);

        Console.WriteLine("You are added total number: {0}",numbers.Count);
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your adding Number are: {0}", number);
        }
```