# Duck typing in the C# compiler

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, idisposable, duck-typing

**Note** This is *not* a question about how to implement or emulate duck typing in C#...

For several years I was under the impression that certain C# language features were depdendent on data structures defined in the language itself (which always seemed like an odd chicken & egg scenario to me). For example, I was under the impression that the `foreach` loop was only available to use with types that implemented `IEnumerable`.

Since then I've come to understand that the C# compiler uses duck typing to determine whether an object can be used in a foreach loop, looking for a `GetEnumerator` method rather than `IEnumerable`. This makes a lot of sense as it removes the chicken & egg conundrum.

I'm a little confused as to why this doesn't seem to be the case with the `using` block and `IDisposable`. Is there any particular reason the compiler can't use duck typing and look for a `Dispose` method? What's the reason for this inconsistency?

Perhaps there's something else going on under the hood with IDisposable?

*Discussing why you would **ever** have an object with a Dispose method that didn't implement IDisposable is outside the scope of this question :)*

Comment: +1 Interesting.  Can you provide a source for the point about `foreach`?

Comment: @harpo I just "discovered" what MattDavey did. I am posting some code as an answer below, though it is technically not an answer per se.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a blog post about this shortly after this question was asked: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx

Comment: Here is good explanation regarding the point about foreach, http://stackoverflow.com/a/398996/1160036. In short, objects don't need to implement `IEnumerable` interface, they just need a `GetEnumerator()` method which returns an object which has `MoveNext()` and `Current`.

Comment: @MattDavey that link doesn't work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's nothing special about `IDisposable` here - but there *is* something special about iterators.

Before C# 2, using this duck type on `foreach` was the *only* way you could implement a strongly-typed iterator, and also the only way of iterating over value types without boxing. I *suspect* that if C# and .NET had had generics to start with, `foreach` would have *required* `IEnumerable<T>` instead, and not had the duck typing.

Now the compiler uses this sort of duck typing in a couple of other places I can think of:

- Collection initializers look for a suitable `Add` overload (as well as the type having to implement `IEnumerable`, just to show that it really is a collection of some kind); this allows for flexible adding of single items, key/value pairs etc
- LINQ (`Select` etc) - this is how LINQ achieves its flexibility, allowing the same query expression format against multiple types, without having to change `IEnumerable<T>` itself
- The C# 5 await expressions require `GetAwaiter` to return an awaiter type which has `IsCompleted` / `OnCompleted` / `GetResult`

In both cases this makes it easier to add the feature to existing types and interfaces, where the concept didn't exist earlier on.

Given that `IDisposable` has been in the framework since the very first version, I don't think there would be any benefit in duck typing the `using` statement. I know you explicitly tried to discount the reasons for having `Dispose` without implementing `IDisposable` from the discussion, but I think it's a crucial point. There need to be good reasons to implement a feature in the language, and I would argue that duck typing is a feature above-and-beyond supporting a known interface. If there's no clear benefit in doing so, it won't end up in the language.

Comment: Expression creation (from lambda) is another example; however, that isn't strictly documented anywhere

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for the answer Jon! Does the compiler use duck typing with collection initializers too? (ie. looking for an Add() method rather than ICollection)

Comment: The use of duck-typing with "for each" allows the compiler to avoid boxing in cases where the iterator is a struct.  While I would consider it bad juju for a struct to implement IEnumerator (generic or not) it can sometimes be advantageous to avoid creating a new object every time loop a loop starts.  Having a GetEnumerator method return a struct and an IEnumerable.GetEnumerator method return a class implementing IEnumerator may allow the best of both worlds.

Comment: Incidentally, it's worth noting that at least in VB if the return type of GetEnumerator is IEnumerable, the compiler will check *at runtime* to see if it implements IDisposable; if the return type is something else, the compiler will check *at compile time*, but will *not* check at runtime.  Even if the enumerator is a derived type that implements IDisposable, if the *declared* type does not implement IDisposable the compiler won't try to call it at runtime.

Comment: This can create a problem if a class has an enumerator that does not require IDisposable, but the enumerator of a derived class would require it.  Using anything other than IEnumerable&lt;T&gt; as the return type for a GetEnumerator method may prevent derived classes from specifying new enumeration methods.

Comment: I was concerned that a struct that implements IDisposable could get boxed via a using statement, but it appears (tested in CLR Profiler) that is not the case. Which makes sense, since the compiler knows I'm "using" a struct. (In contrast the compiler cannot know that the IEnumerator returned from IEnumerable.GetEnumerator is a struct -- for example GetEnumerator could conditionally return different types of enumerators.)

Comment: @yoyo: The compiler *can* tell that the value returned from the `GetEnumerator` method is a struct if it calls a specific method though - that's why `List<T>` uses explicit interface implementation for `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, but a `foreach` loop over something *known* to be a `List<T>` will call `List<T>.GetEnumerator` which returns a `List<T>.Enumerator` struct.

Comment: Yup, you're right. that's what I tried to say with "from IEnumerable.GetEnumerator" -- if the compiler only knows it has an IEnumerable to iterate over then it can't know what type of enumerator it's going to get.

Answer (score 15):

There's no chicken and egg:  `foreach` could depend on `IEnumerable` since `IEnumerable` doesn't depend on `foreach`.  The reason foreach is permitted on collections not implementing `IEnumerable` is probably [largely historic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> In C#, it is not strictly necessary
>   for a collection class to inherit from
>   IEnumerable and IEnumerator in order
>   to be compatible with foreach; as long
>   as the class has the required
>   GetEnumerator, MoveNext, Reset, and
>   Current members, it will work with
>   foreach. Omitting the interfaces has
>   the advantage of allowing you to
>   define the return type of Current to
>   be more specific than object, thereby
>   providing type-safety.

Furthermore, not all chicken and egg problems are actually problems: for example a function can call itself (recursion!) or a reference type can contain itself (like a linked list).

So when `using` came around why would they use something as tricky to specify as duck typing when they can simply say: implement `IDisposable`?  Fundamentally, by using duck typing you're doing an end-run around the type system, which is only useful when the type system is insufficient (or impractical) to address a problem.

Comment: The chicken & egg scenario I was referring to is that a language feature might depend on a type which is defined in the language itself. eg. IEnumerable depends on C#, and C# (foreach) depends on IEnumerable...

Comment: Well, in that sense lots of stuff is chicken+eggy: the language feature `+` for integral addition depends on `int` which is defined in the language.  It's just part of one big picture :-)

Comment: Thinking about it more, it's not the C# language which depends on the interfaces, rather it's the C# compiler, so we have a triangle of dependency :)

Comment: @MattDavey Rather than `+`, a better example would be `delegete`. This is just another name of `System.Delegate`, a normal class that you can call it with its static `Combine` or `Remove` methods. But now you have `+=` and `-=` operators depend on it.

Comment: In C# 7.2 and up, a `ref struct` can implement the Disposable pattern (`void Dispose`) without implementing the `IDisposable` interface, and it can be used with the `using` statement. As it stands (C# 12), other types must still explicitly implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 1):

The question which you are asking is not a chicken and egg situation. Its more like hows the language compiler is implemented. Like C# and VB.NET compiler are implemented differently.If you write a simple code of hello world and compile it with both the compiler and inspect the IL code they will be different. Coming back to your question, I will like to explain what IL code is generated by C# compiler for `IEnumerable`.

```
IEnumerator e = arr.GetEnumerator();

while(e.MoveNext())
{
   e.Currrent;
}
```

So the C# compiler is tweaked for the case of `foreach`.

Comment: 11 years later I wanted to come back and upvote this answer. I don't know much about language/compiler design but I do know that language/compiler writers love to 'bootstrap' their compiler by writing it in it's own language as soon as possible. What I perceived to be a chicken & egg situation is actually a symbiotic relationship between the language and compiler.