# C# language design - ducktyping

Tags: c#, language-design

C# is mostly stronglt typed, however, there are a few odd behaviors:

e.g. when rolling your own enumerator class, you do not have to implement IEnumerable, you only have to implement a method called GetEnuerator(), you will still be able to `foreach`over it.

Same goes for some of the Linq support, you can write your own Linq provider just by providing some `select` `where` methods etc.

So why is IDisposable required for the `using(x){}` statement?

I do get why the linq provider can be written in such a way since there is no fixed contract to fullfill, only a sort of pattern of methods.

Why was the C# compiler(or language spec?) designed in such a way that interfaces are needed for some of the built in language constructs, but not for others?

Comment: Eric Lippert explains it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx

Comment: Re "weakly typed": http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929697/395760 (plus, none of the numerous definitions of weak typing I know would cover this: It *is* type-checked statically, just structurally instead of nominally.)

Comment: So, `foreach` is designed the way it is because .NET did not have generics back when it first came out. interesting :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duck typing in the C# compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368967/duck-typing-in-the-c-sharp-compiler)

Comment: @JohnKoerner yes, duplicate. wonder why SO didn't show that question as a hint when naming this one.. odd