# var won't work with DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, .net, var, datagridviewrow

I new to C# and have a question regarding the use of "var"

When I use the following code everything works great

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in myGrid.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains("51000"))
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = "X";
    }
}
```

But when I change `DataGridViewRow` to `var` I get and error that states

> 'object' does not contain definition for 'Cells' and no extension
>   method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it sounds like c# is trying to imply the wrong type for DataGridViewRow, this happens when there are ambigous definitiions for myGrid.Rows

Comment: You will have the same issue with `foreach (var row in dt.Rows)` where `dt` is a `DataTable`, but explicitly specifying `foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)` works fine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the `GridView.Rows` property returns a `GridViewRowCollection` type.

In this case `var` can't infer from usage that the object will be a `DataGridViewRow` inside.

Source: [GridView.Rows Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 28):

[`myGrid.Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) is of type [`DataGridViewRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx).

This thing is pretty old, its definition reads:

```
public class DataGridViewRowCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable, IList
```

Do you see the non-generic interfaces? This class could implement `IList<DataGridViewRow>` and then `var` would just work, but it's legacy.

`IEnumerable` conveys no information about the item type, and the [`GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356717.aspx) function doesn't help here, because it returns an `IEnumerator`, while it could return an `IEnumerator<DataGridViewRow>`.

Essentially, the C# compiler looks for a `GetEnumerator` function which returns an object which has a `MoveNext` function and a `Current` property (*or* an `IEnumerable<T>`/`IEnumerable` interface when implemented explicitly). This [*duck-typing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369023/3764814) approach is for historical reasons, it existed before generics were introduced into the language. The `foreach` loop variable will be of the same type than the `Current` property. And within [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) (the non-generic variant), [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) is of type `object`.

Specifying the type explicitly:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myGrid.Rows)
```

simply casts the return value of `Current` to a `DataGridViewRow`, for lack of a better mechanism.

You could also use LINQ to achieve the same effect, if you *really want* to use that `var` keyword here:

```
foreach (var row in myGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
```

This works, because the [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) *extension method* returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which in turn makes use of [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx), and `T` ends up as the type of the [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7.aspx) property of the enumerator, so the type information is propagated.

I doubt you'll benefit from these details *at this point*, but you may want to keep this for further reference when you'll learn more about the language. You'd have to learn about extension methods and generic types to grasp this.

Comment: Yes I see now.  Thank you for you in deep explanation.

Answer (score 5):

`DataGridViewRow.Rows` is of type [DataGridViewRowCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), which doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`, only `IEnumerable`. And `object` is the best guess which compiler can infer when you don't specify cast to `DataGridViewRow` for `row`

Comment: Correct... but explain why only implementing `IEnumerable` causes type `object` to be inferred...

Comment: Correct. The asker would expect that in 2015 we would have passed the old non-generic .NET 1 days (.NET 2 and generics came in 2005). But with [`DataGridViewRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx), no.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the DataGridViewRow to Var C# is unsure that there is an array called cells. To fix this you could cast the var as a DataGridViewRow however it is almost always better to use the type if you know it, look online for type safety to get more information.

Comment: I agree that using the type is always better.  I was just tinkering with the how and was wondering why var would not work but I get it now - thanks

Comment: `var` is type-safe; there's nothing wrong with using it when available. The *compiler* infers the type, so the code is compiled exactly as if you had specified it yourself. It's really just syntactic sugar to save you typing out long class-names (and for anonymous types, of course).