# Can the C# compiler use duck typing with foreach over a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, duck-typing

It's been established that the compiler can do duck typing to remove some overhead when iterating over a List or an Array (see [Duck typing in the C# compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368967/duck-typing-in-the-c-sharp-compiler)), as those types implement their IEnumerator as a stack-allocated struct.

Is this the case even when the type is generic, but constrained to implement IEnumerable?

To give more specifity, could option B run with less overhead than A?

A:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> collection)
{
    foreach (var subCollection in collection)
        foreach (var element in subCollection)
            yield return element;
}
```

B:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<TList, T>(this TList collection)
    where TList : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    foreach (var subCollection in collection)
        foreach (var element in subCollection)
            yield return element;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, basically. The only use for "B" is when the `TList` **itself** is actually a `struct`; the IL can then use "constrained call" to call the original `GetEnumerator()` **without** any part having to box the original `struct TList` value.

But: once you've called `GetEnumerator()`, you're back into `IEnumerator<T>` land, and it will **not** use the custom iterator.

All of which is mostly moot in this case, because iterator blocks are *also* fairly "allocatey". So... if avoiding boxing the `TList` is your concern, you are presumably obsessive about allocations: in which case you wouldn't write the iterator block this way, either.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer has indicated, the method that gets called in the `TList` version will always be `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`, even if it is hidden in `TList` and another `GetEnumerator` is visible.
Therefore, even if `TList` happens to be `List<T>`, version B cannot take advantage of `List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()` and the enumerator structure will be boxed inside the call to `IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`.

We can upgrade `IEnumerable` in a **backward compatible** way as follows:

```cs
interface IEnumerable<out T, out TEnumerator> : IEnumerable<T>
  where TEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
{
  new TEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}

// In an imagined upgrade, the compiler should transform the iterator block
// to return IEnumerable<T, IEnumerator<T>>, allowing this to chain.
static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T, TOuterEnumerator, TInnerEnumerator>
  (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T, TInnerEnumerator>, TOuterEnumerator> collection)
  // C# compiler needs to be reminded of these constraints,
  // or foreach will not compile.
  where TOuterEnumerator : IEnumerator<IEnumerable<T, TInnerEnumerator>>
  where TInnerEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
{
  foreach (var subcoll in collection)
    foreach (var elem in subcoll)
      yield return elem;
}
```

> `IEnumerable<T, IEnumerator<T>>` will be the new self of `IEnumerable<T>`, just like how `IEnumerable<object>` is the new self of `IEnumerable`.
> In this imagined upgrade, `List<T>` should implement `IEnumerable<T, List<T>.Enumerator>`.

The compiler will expand `foreach` to use `TOuterEnumerator` and `TInnerEnumerator` as the static types of the enumerators, so no boxing will happen if they happen to be structures.

Note that the compiler will always choose `IEnumerator<...>.MoveNext` and `IEnumerator<...>.Current`, even if the enumerator types hide them and have another visible version. This is the different from a non-generic method, which will choose the visible version, be it `IEnumerator<...>` or the specific types.

This does not cause a correctness problem for any sane enumerator (in fact, I don't know any enumerator implementing `IEnumerator<...>` explicitly).
This also should not cause performance issues, because the compiler will constrain the call using the knowledge of the static types of the enumerators.
So if the enumerators are `sealed class` or structure, the interface (virtual) call goes away and is replaced by direct instance call.

---

Shameless self-advertising: I have [a blog entry on this](https://geelaw.blog/entries/csharp-generics-duck-typing/).