# Can a class support try-with-resources without implementing AutoCloseable interface?

Tags: java

I see that *try-with-resources* is available to any class that implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.

```java
public interface AutoCloseable {
  void close() throws Exception;
}
```

Is that the only criteria for a class to support *try-with-resources* in Java (I meant, are there any possible scenarios where a class **doesn't** implement `AutoCloseable` interface but supports *try-with-resources*)?

Comment: `AutoCloseable` is a .NET-twin of `IDisposable`, have a look how the C# world uses duck typing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368967/duck-typing-in-the-c-sharp-compiler

Answer (score 5):

From [§14.20.3 of the *Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> **The type of a variable declared or referred to as a resource in a resource specification must be a subtype of `AutoCloseable`, or a compile-time error occurs.**

In other words, only instances of `AutoCloseable` can be used with try-with-resources.

---

Note on terminology (also explained in the same section of the JLS). If you have:

```java
try (AutoCloseable foo = ...;
     AutoCloseable bar = ...) {
  // do stuff...
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // handle exception...
}
```

Then the "resource specification" is:

```
(AutoCloseable foo = ...;
 AutoCloseable bar = ...)
```

And there are two "resources": `foo` and `bar`.