# Reversing an ienumerable of lambda functions

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have created an ienumerable of lambda functions using this function

```
    static IEnumerable<Func<int>> MakeEnumerator(int[] values)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < values.Length; a++)
        {
            yield return () => Values[a];
        }
    }
```

I cannot then reverse this using LINQ or convert into an array without all the values becoming the last function.
Example code (note this just demonstrates the problem it is not the code in the application):

```
        int[] start = {1,2,3};

        IEnumerable<Func<int>> end = MakeEnumerator(start).Reverse<Func<int>>();

        foreach (Func<int> i in end)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i());
        }
```

I think the problem is in the MakeEnumerator function. How would I modify this to make it work or go about writing a working replacement reverse function.

Comment: Code inspection tools like Resharper will show a warning and often a proposed solution in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're capturing the loop variable. All of your delegates are capturing the same variable, so they'll always see the latest value of `a`... which will be `values.Length + 1` by the time you're executing the delegates, in your use cases. You can simply copy it instead:

```
for (int a = 0; a < values.Length; a++)
{
    int copy = a;
    yield return () => Values[copy];
}
```

Alternatively (and preferrably IMO) use a `foreach` loop, which *currently* requires the same workaround:

```
foreach (int value in values)
{
    int copy = value;
    yield return () => copy;
}
```

Or better yet:

```
return values.Select(x => (Func<int>)(() => x));
```

Or:

```
Func<int, Func<int>> projection = x => () => x;
return values.Select(projection);
```

See Eric Lippert's blog post ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for more information. Note that the behaviour of `foreach` may well be changing for C# 4.5.

Comment: Is there anything solid (aka something in writing somewhere) yet in regards to the planned changes for `foreach`?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Eric Lippert has made reasonably confident predictions that it will be changing, in comments here on Stack Overflow. I haven't seen anything definitive in a blog post though.

Comment: Why did you not simply write `yield return () => value;`?

Comment: Have you seen anything about `foreach` changing besides http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350495/whats-going-on-behind-the-scene-of-the-foreach-loop/7350562#7350562?

Comment: @Nawaz: That would suffer the same problem - it would be the `value` variable which was captured; the same variable for all iterations.

Comment: @Gabe: Just other comments, usually on my answers.

Comment: @Jon: Wouldn't it return a *copy* of value? Why? Have you covered this in your book? I want to read this in detail.

Comment: @Nawaz: Have you tried following the link at the bottom of the answer?  I do cover it in the book, I believe, but Eric's post goes into more detail.

Comment: @Jon: Ohh.. you've edited the answer, making it more perfect. Thanks. I'll read that. +1.

Answer (score 2):

All of your lambda expressions are [sharing the same `a` variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).
Since you're only calling them after the loop finishes, `a` is always `3`.

You need to give each one its own variable:

```
for (int dontUse = 0; dontUse < values.Length; dontUse++)
{
    int a = dontUse;
    yield return () => Values[a];
}
```

In this code, each lambda expression gets its own `a` variable (since it's scoped inside the loop), and these separate variables never change.