# How is foreach implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, foreach, language-implementation, language-specifications

How exactly is `foreach` implemented in C#?

I imagine a part of it looking like:

```
var enumerator = TInput.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  // do some stuff here
}
```

However I'm unsure what's really going on. What methodology is used for returning `enumerator.Current` for each cycle? Does it return [for each cycle] or does it take an anonymous function or something to execute the body of `foreach`?

Comment: Essentially, `// do some stuff here` gets replaced with the inside of the `foreach` loop "before" compilation. (Or rather, the compiler generates equivalent bytecode.)

Comment: This is how it is implemented  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/Statements/ForEach.cs,fd6f1b9d9e676ae4

Comment: Not really a duplicate of linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982/how-do-foreach-loops-work-in-c). Only the title remotely matches, but the body ask quite something else.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It doesn't use an anonymous function, no. Basically the compiler converts the code into something *broadly equivalent* to the while loop you've shown here.

`foreach` *isn't* a function call - it's built-into the language itself, just like `for` loops and `while` loops. There's no need for it to return anything or "take" a function of any kind.

Note that `foreach` has a few interesting wrinkles:

- When iterating over an array (known at compile-time) the compiler can use a loop counter and compare with the length of the array instead of using an `IEnumerator`
- `foreach` will dispose of the iterator at the end; that's simple for `IEnumerator<T>` which extends `IDisposable`, but as `IEnumerator` *doesn't*, the compiler inserts a check to test at execution time whether the iterator implements `IDisposable`
- You can iterate over types which don't implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`, so long as you have an applicable `GetEnumerator()` method which returns a type with suitable `Current` and `MoveNext()` members. As noted in comments, a type can *also* implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` explicitly, but have a public `GetEnumerator()` method which returns a type other than `IEnumerator`/`IEnumerator<T>`. See [`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765.aspx) for an example - this avoids creating a reference type object unnecessarily in many cases.

See section 8.8.4 of the C# 4 spec for more information.

Comment: Your third bullet isn't just for types that don't implement `IEnumerable`: when a type does implement it and also provides a `GetEnumerator` method that's different from `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`, the type's own `GetEnumerator` will be used. The standard class `List<T>` is a good example.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet! Out of interest, is there a parameter type that we can use in C# that looks like `Type x in collection`. Can we use this dialect ourselves?

Comment: @JamieDixon: I don't understand what you're asking, I'm afraid.

Comment: When we use a `foreach` we use the syntax `int x in collection` as in `foreach(int x in collection)`. Is it possible to use this syntax as a property of a standard method?

Comment: For fun I've had a go at implementing my own foreach. I've written about it here: http://www.jamie-dixon.co.uk/csharp/implementing-a-custom-foreach-iterator/

Comment: It's not clear why you haven't just used `Action<T>`, modelling this on `List<T>.ForEach`. And why are you using the non-generic `IEnumerable`? Also, lambda expressions don't need to be nearly as explicit in many cases :)

Comment: Ah of course. I've changed my local code to use Action<T> and negated the types from the lambda. As for the non-generic IEnumerable, that's just an issue with me not checking wordpress before pushing submit. I'm actually using the generic version. I'll fix that now.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think a word on the casting involved would make this answer complete..

Answer (score 12):

Surprised the exact implementation is not touched. While what you have posted in the question is the simplest form, the complete implementation (including enumerator disposal, casting etc) is in the [8.8.4 section of the spec.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Now there are 2 scenarios where a `foreach` loop can be run on a type:

1. **If the type has a public/non-static/non-generic/parameterless method named `GetEnumerator` which returns something that has a public `MoveNext` method and a public `Current` property.** [As noted by Mr Eric Lippert in this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx), this was designed so as to accommodate pre generic era for both type safety and boxing related performance issues in case of value types. Note that this a case of *duck typing*. For instance this works:

   ```
   class Test
   {
       public SomethingEnumerator GetEnumerator()
       {

       }
   }

   class SomethingEnumerator
   {
       public Something Current //could return anything
       {
           get { return ... }
       }

       public bool MoveNext()
       {

       }
   }

   //now you can call
   foreach (Something thing in new Test()) //type safe
   {

   }
   ```

   This is then translated by the compiler to:

   ```
   E enumerator = (collection).GetEnumerator();
   try {
      ElementType element; //pre C# 5
      while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
         ElementType element; //post C# 5
         element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current;
         statement;
      }
   }
   finally {
      IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
      if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
   }
   ```
2. **If the type implements `IEnumerable` where the`GetEnumerator` returns `IEnumerator` that has a public `MoveNext` method and a public `Current` property.** But an interesting sub case is that even if you implement `IEnumerable` explicitly (ie no public `GetEnumerator` method on `Test` class), you can have a `foreach`.

   ```
   class Test : IEnumerable
   {
       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   This is because in this case `foreach` is implemented as (provided there is no other public `GetEnumerator` method in the class):

   ```
   IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)(collection)).GetEnumerator();
   try {
       ElementType element; //pre C# 5
       while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
           ElementType element; //post C# 5
           element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current;
           statement;
      }
   }
   finally {
       IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
       if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
   }
   ```

   If the type implements `IEnumerable<T>` explicitly then the `foreach` is converted to (provided there is no other public `GetEnumerator` method in the class):

   ```
   IEnumerator<T> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<T>)(collection)).GetEnumerator();
   try {
       ElementType element; //pre C# 5
       while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
           ElementType element; //post C# 5
           element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current; //Current is `T` which is cast
           statement;
      }
   }
   finally {
       enumerator.Dispose(); //Enumerator<T> implements IDisposable
   }
   ```

---

Few interesting things to note are:

1. In both the above cases the `Enumerator` class should have a public `MoveNext` method and a public `Current` property. In other words, **if you're implementing `IEnumerator` interface it has to be implemented implicitly.** For eg, `foreach` wont work for this enumerator:

   ```
   public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
   {
       void IEnumerator.Reset()
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       object IEnumerator.Current
       {
           get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
       }

       bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   (Thanks Roy Namir for pointing this out. `foreach` implementation isnt as easy it seems on the surface)
2. Enumerator precedence - It goes like if you have a `public GetEnumerator` method, then that is the default choice of `foreach` irrespective of who is implementing it. For example:

   ```
   class Test : IEnumerable<int>
   {
       public SomethingEnumerator GetEnumerator()
       {
           //this one is called
       }

       IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   If you don't have a public implementation (ie only explicit implementation), then precedence goes like `IEnumerator<T>` > `IEnumerator`.
3. There is a cast operator involved in the implementation of `foreach` where the collection element is cast back to the type (specified in the `foreach` loop itself). Which means even if you had written the `SomethingEnumerator` like this:

   ```
   class SomethingEnumerator
   {
       public object Current //returns object this time
       {
           get { return ... }
       }

       public bool MoveNext()
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   You could write:

   ```
   foreach (Something thing in new Test())
   {

   }
   ```

   Because `Something` is type compatible with `object`, going by C# rules ,or in other words, the compiler lets it if there is an explicit cast possible between the two types. Otherwise the compiler prevents it. The actual cast is performed at run time which may or may not fail.

Comment: The article you're thinking of is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, I will update it..

Comment: Of course, if *either* `IEnumerable` *or* `IEnumerable<X>` for one type `X` (`IEnumerable<Y>` could be implemented differently in pathological cases) is implemented implicitly, then surely there is a "valid" `public` `GetEnumerator`, so that falls under case 1. above. (We disregard the case where `GetEnumerator` from a base class is *hidden* by an identical overload in the relevant type.) But if you implement the interfaces explicitly, you can still have a "bad" public `GetEnumerator`. For example if you have `public void/* bad */ GetEnumerator() { }`, the `IEnumerable` will not be considered.

Comment: Case 1. is attempted if `GetEnumerator` is public, non-static, non-generic and takes zero parameters, if I remember correctly. If `GetEnumerator` is not like that, or doesn't exist, `IEnumerable<>` or `IEnumerable` is considered.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Surely, that falls under case 1. If there is a public `GetEnumerator` that is all it matters. I did mention it in the answer. As an example, I put a more surprising case, ie, a simple standalone public `GetEnumerator` which can override the explicit ones even if they are from IEnumerable interfaces. And of course it should be non generic and non static as well, which I will update. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342847/c-sharp-foreach-behaviour-clarification