# Multiple IEnumerable implementations paradox

Tags: c#, inheritance, ienumerable

1. I have a generic class A<*T*>, that implements IEnumerable<*T[]*>.
2. I want to have a convenience wrapper B that inherits from A<*char*> and implements IEnumerable<*string*>.

   ```
   public class A<T> : IEnumerable<T[]>
   {
       public IEnumerator<T[]> GetEnumerator()
       {
           return Enumerate().GetEnumerator();
       }

       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {
           return GetEnumerator();
       }

       protected IEnumerable<T[]> Enumerate()
       {
           throw new System.NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   public class B : A<char>, IEnumerable<string>
   {
       public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
       {
           return Enumerate().Select(s => new string(s)).GetEnumerator();
       }

       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {
           return GetEnumerator();
       }
   }
   ```

Now, this works perfectly fine, foreach variable type is inferred to be string:

```
B b = new B();
foreach (var s in b)
{
    string[] split = s.Split(' ');
}
```

But this won't compile, saying "The type arguments cannot be inferred from usage, try specifying the type arguments explicitly":

```
string[] strings = b.ToArray();
```

However, this works:

```
string[] strings = b.ToArray<string>();
```

Can anyone explain this compiler behavior?

Obviously, B implements both IEnumerable<*char[]*> and IEnumerable<*string*> and probably it can't figure out which of them I want to call, but why it works fine in "foreach" sample?

Please, don't suggest me to solve my problem by composition - this is the last resort for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the following:

`foreach` actually looks for a public method called `GetEnumerator`. It doesn't really care for `IEnumerable<T>`. Your class `B` only has one public method named `GetEnumerator`: The one defined in `B` which *hides* the one defined in `A`.

`ToArray` on the other hand is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. As your class is both `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable<char[]>` the call is ambiguous between the two generic arguments `string` and `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` loop does not use `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` implementation. You can use `foreach` even if your class doesn't implement any of them. The only thing it needs is `GetEnumerator` method that returns `IEnumerator` implementation.

Check this question: [How is foreach implemented in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179156/how-is-foreach-implemented-in-c)

That's why your class works with `foreach` and doesn't with `ToArray()`.