# In c# does foreach call method in each loop?

Tags: c#

I came across this in our codebase:

```
foreach (var evtType in EventLocator.GetTypes())
```

and remembering *Shlemiel the painter's algorithm* does the method `EventLocator.GetTypes()` get called on each loop or just the once?

Comment: This is also relevant, but closed as duplicate: [How is foreach implemented in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11179156/7586)

Comment: @Kobi I can see why you marked this as a duplicate but I couldn't see the answer to my question in the answer you linked as I wanted to know if the method that returns a collection is called on each loop or just the once.  All the examples in the question you linked used prefabricated collections that weren't returned from a method.

Comment: I only closed after making sure [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/398996/7586) is there, under "A foreach loop [...] kinda equates to". `var tmp = obj.GetEnumerator();` shows the method is only called once, to create an enumerator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expession designating collection being iterated is conceptually captured into a local variable before the loop starts. It is executed only once.

You can derive this fact just by logic. Imagine the source was an `IEnumerable<T>` that is stateful. How would you continue the loop if you discarded the old object and reexecuted the source expression? You can't index into a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it doesn't. `EventLocator.GetTypes()` will be optimized by compiler to a variable in outer scope

Comment: This is not an optimization. This behavior is forced by the language spec and cannot be any other way.

Comment: @usr Then it's even better behavior :)