# C# `foreach` behaviour — Clarification?

Tags: c#, foreach

*I've read Eric's article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) about foreach enumeration and about the different scenarios where foreach can work*

In order to prevent the old C# version to do boxing , the C# team enabled duck typing for foreach to run on a non- Ienumerable collection.(A public `GetEnumerator` that return something that has public `MoveNext` and `Current` property is sufficient(.

So ,  Eric wrote a [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAbAT.png) :

```
class MyIntegers : IEnumerable
{
  public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
  {
    private int index = 0;
    object IEnumerator.Current { return this.Current; }
    int Current { return index * index; }
    public bool MoveNext() 
    { 
      if (index > 10) return false;
      ++index;
      return true;
    }
  }
  public MyEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return new MyEnumerator(); }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

But I believe it has some typos *(missing get accessor at `Current` property implementation)* which prevent it from compiling (I've already Emailed him).

*Anyway* here is a working version :

```
class MyIntegers : IEnumerable
{
  public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
  {
    private int index = 0;
      public void Reset()
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      object IEnumerator.Current {
          get { return this.Current; }
      }
    int Current {
        get { return index*index; }
    }
    public bool MoveNext() 
    { 
      if (index > 10) return false;
      ++index;
      return true;
    }
  }
  public MyEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return new MyEnumerator(); }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

Ok.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx) :

> A type `C` is said to be a `collection type` if it implements the
>   `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface **or** implements the
>   `collection pattern` by meeting **all** of the following criteria:

- C contains a public instance method with the signature GetEnumerator() that returns a struct-type, class-type, or interface-type, which is called E in the following text.
- E contains a public instance method with the signature MoveNext() and the return type bool.
- E contains a public instance property named Current that permits reading the current value. The type of this property is said to be the element type of the collection type.

OK.  Let's match the docs to Eric's sample

Eric's sample  *is* said to be a `collection type` because it does implements the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface ( explicitly though).  But it is **not(!)** a `collection pattern` because of bullet 3 : `MyEnumerator` does *not*  public instance property named Current.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx) says :

> If the collection expression is of a type that implements the
>   collection pattern (as defined above), the expansion of the foreach
>   statement is:

```
E enumerator = (collection).GetEnumerator();
try {
   while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      ElementType element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current;
      statement;
   }
}
finally {
   IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
   if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

> **Otherwise** , The collection expression is of a type that implements
>   **System.IEnumerable (!)**, and the expansion of the foreach statement is:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = 
        ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)(collection)).GetEnumerator();
try {
   while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      ElementType element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current;
      statement;
   }
}
finally {
   IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
   if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

**Question #1**

It seems that Eric's sample  neither  implements the
 `collection pattern`  nor `System.IEnumerable` -   so it's not supposed to match *any* of the condition specified above. So how come I can still iterate it via :

```
 foreach (var element in (new MyIntegers() as IEnumerable ))
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(element);
             }
```

**Question #2**

Why do I have to mention `new MyIntegers() as IEnumerable` ? it's already Ienumerable (!!) and even after  that , Isn't the compiler is already doing the job by itself via casting :

```
((System.Collections.IEnumerable)(collection)).GetEnumerator() ?
```

It is right here :

```
 IEnumerator enumerator = 
            ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)(collection)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
       while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
       ...
```

So why it still wants me to mention as Ienumerable ?

Comment: Now we know the question is primarily about the `System.IEnumerable` typo, I will also mention that this language specification should have allowed your sample without the cast to work by falling back to using `IEnumerable` interface. The specification never mentions raising an error when the collection pattern is partially implemented (which is what I addressed in my answer by highlighting the C# 5.0 specification does explain this error).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> MyEnumerator does not has the required public methods

Yes it does - or rather, it would if `Current` were public. All that's required is that it has:

- A public, readable `Current` property
- A public `MoveNext()` method with no type arguments returning `bool`

The lack of `public` here was just another typo, basically. As it is, the example doesn't do what it's meant to (prevent boxing). It's using the `IEnumerable` implementation because you're using `new MyIntegers() as IEnumerable` - so the expression type is `IEnumerable`, and it just uses the interface throughout.

You claim that it doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, (which is `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, btw) but it does, using explicit interface implementation.

It's easiest to test this sort of thing *without* implementing `IEnumerable` at all:

```
using System;

class BizarreCollection
{
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator();
    }

    public class Enumerator
    {
        private int index = 0;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (index == 10)
            {
                return false;
            }
            index++;
            return true;
        }

        public int Current { get { return index; } }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var item in new BizarreCollection())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you make `Current` private, it won't compile.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Ah, true - that's just another typo then. As you say, the existing example wouldn't compile - put `public` in and it's fine. Will edit.

Comment: But it's already all working like that without public http://i.imgur.com/gxqaEeq.png

Comment: @RoyiNamir: In that case the compiler is falling back to treating the enumerator as an `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the `IEnumerator` interface have a `Current` property force it to be public by default?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Nope - if you use explicit interface implementation, it isn't public in the normal way.

Comment: All interface members as well as their implementation must be accessed somehow so they are either public or internal

Comment: Jon I don't understand. so to which code of foreach it is translated to  ? first or second ?

Comment: @Fabjan: No, that's not true. Explicit interface implementation messes with stuff, basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean by this "messes with stuff" ?

Comment: @Fabjan: I mean that code which isn't public in the language spec terms is still accessible via the interface. It doesn't count as a public member for the purposes of member lookup.

Comment: @JonSkeet all interface methods that are implemented explicitly are public by default so that's why we can't use public access modifier explicitly in class (it'll not compile this way).

Comment: Jon , (_when you're back..._) : the example still does boxing like you said . so the foreach is translated to `(collection).GetEnumerator();` but if so ( regarding question #2 of myne) - why do I have to mention `as Ienumerbale` in `foreach (var element in (new MyIntegers() as IEnumerable ))` ? it's already Ienumerable !

Comment: @RoyiNamir: With all the snippets going on (and your example which is a screenshot rather than something I can cut and paste) it's not clear where you're "having" to specify that, or what happens if you don't. If it's failing to compile without that, it's because it's finding the `GetEnumerator` method without that actually satisfying the pattern. But it *does* implement `IEnumerable` - I'm not sure why you think it doesn't.

Comment: @Fabjan: No, they're *not* public by default - not in the normal way. From the C# 5 spec: "Explicit interface member implementations have different accessibility characteristics than other members. Because explicit interface member implementations are never accessible through their fully qualified name in a method invocation or a property access, they are in a sense private. However, since they can be accessed through an interface instance, they are in a sense also public." That "in a sense" is really important - because any time the compiler is checking for public members, it *won't* find it.

Comment: Jon , But MSDN say ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx) : _Otherwise, the collection expression is of a type that implements System.IEnumerable(!!!), and the expansion of the foreach statement is:_ `IEnumerator enumerator = 
        ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)(collection)).GetEnumerator()` -  (which is what you said my code is at) -  but my code is NOT implementing `System.IEnumerable` but `System.Collection.Ienumerable` ....so ?

Comment: @Royi: That's an MSDN typo. There's no such interface as System.IEnumerable.

Comment: @JonSkeet Now you see why I was stuck because I couldn't understand how my code falls into each category. So many typos in the article and msdn i was completely lost !

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I'd suggest using the C# Language Specification separate document (you can download various versions [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx)) - it's generally of better quality than MSDN, in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

The reference to `System.IEnumerable` on the MSDN is nothing more than a typo in an old language specification, no such interface exists, I believe it should be referring to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

You should really read the language specification of the version of C# you are using, the C# 5.0 language specification is available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029).

Some further information about why failing to cast this example results in an error rather than falling back to using `System.Collections.IEnumerable`:

In the specification for `foreach` (section 8.8.4) you will see the rules have slightly changed (some steps have been cut for brevity):

> - Perform member lookup on the type X with identifier GetEnumerator and no type arguments. If the member lookup does not produce a match, or it produces an ambiguity, or produces a match that is not a method group, check for an enumerable interface as described below. It is recommended that a warning be issued if member lookup produces anything except a method group or no match.
> - Perform overload resolution using the resulting method group and an empty argument list. If overload resolution results in no applicable methods, results in an ambiguity, or results in a single best method but that method is either static or not public, check for an enumerable interface as described below. It is recommended that a warning be issued if overload resolution produces anything except an unambiguous public instance method or no applicable methods.
> - If the return type E of the GetEnumerator method is not a class, struct or interface type, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
> - Member lookup is performed on E with the identifier Current and no type arguments. If the member lookup produces no match, the result is an error, or the result is anything except a public instance property that permits reading, an error is produced and no further steps are taken.
> - The collection type is X, the enumerator type is E, and the element type is the type of the Current property.

So from the first bullet point we would find the `public MyEnumerator GetEnumerator()`, the second and third bullets go through without error. When we get to the fourth bullet point, no public member called `Current` is available which results in the error you are seeing without the cast, this exact situation never gives the compiler the opportunity to look for the enumerable interface.

When you explicitly cast your instance to an `IEnumerable` all of the requirements are satisfied as the type `IEnumerable` and the associated `IEnumerator` satisfy all of the requirements.

Also from the documentation:

> The above steps, if successful, unambiguously produce a collection type C, enumerator type E and element type T. A foreach statement of the form
>
> ```
> foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
> ```
>
> is then expanded to:
>
> ```
> {
>     E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
>     try {
>         while (e.MoveNext()) {
>             V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
>             embedded-statement
>         }
>     }
>     finally {
>         … // Dispose e
>     }
> }
> ```

So given your explicit cast to `IEnumerable`, you will end up with the following:

> - C = `System.Collections.IEnumerable`
> - x = `new MyIntegers() as System.Collections.IEnumerable`
> - E = `System.Collections.IEnumerator`
> - T = `System.Object`
> - V = `System.Object`

```
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerator e = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)(new MyIntegers() as System.Collections.IEnumerable)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            System.Object element = (System.Object)(System.Object)e.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
    }
    finally {
        System.IDisposable d = e as System.IDisposable;
        if (d != null) d.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Which explains why using the cast works.

Comment: What error ? the code compiles as it is  without public `Current` http://i.imgur.com/gxqaEeq.png

Comment: When you cast it to `IEnumerable` it compiles, but that's because you are explicitly using the type `IEnumerable` which satisfies all of the above (`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` returns an `IEnumerator` which has public `MoveNext()` and `Current` members).

Comment: Ok let me understand please. Are you saying that the compiler translates it to the **second** one here — http://i.imgur.com/IfmLD5B.png

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, exactly, will update my answer to show the expansion :)

Comment: But my code implements `System.Collection.IEnumerable` . Not `System.IEnumerable`.  (look at the conditions in my questions  - where the _Otherwise_is in bold

Comment: @RoyiNamir `System.IEnumerable` is a typo in the old language specification, read the up to date language specification and it is no longer there.

Comment: So many typos  it's been over 4 years and nobody took the time to test it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It doesn't surprise me, I didn't read close enough to notice `System.IEnumerable` instead of `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

Comment: Right . That fact of System.Ienumerable  - changed the flow of decision completely.