# How to use Extension method inside a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, foreach

I have an extension method to convert `Address` into a oneline string:

```
public static class AddressExtensions
{
    public static string ToOneLine(this Address address)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(address.Street);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.City)) sb.Append(string.Format("{0}, ",address.City));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.State)) sb.Append(string.Format("{0}, ", address.State));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address.Zip)) sb.Append(string.Format("{0}, ", address.Zip));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I use it to transfer data from domain model into my DTO. The code below uses `foreach` and works fine:

```
var entity=_repository.GetAll();
var model = new List<SummaryViewModel>();
        foreach (var e in entity)
        {
            model.Add(new SummaryViewModel
            {
                Address = e.Address.ToOneLine(),
                Name = e.Name,
                Id = e.Id
            });
        }
```

But when using `LINQ`,

```
        var model = entity.Select(e => new SummaryViewModel
        {
            Address = e.Address.ToOneLine(), Id = e.Id
        }).ToList();
```

I got a `System.NotSupportedException`.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToOneLine
(Domain.Models.Address)' method, and this method cannot be translated 
into a store expression.
```

What happened? I thought both method should work.

What is the correct way to use my extension method inside a LINQ statement?

Comment: that means that sql can't be generated from that.

Comment: Reopened since the solution in the proposed duplicate question does not apply here.

Comment: As Daniel A. White said - extension methods are only available for methods which are "wrapped/implemented" internally in orm. That's why it's considered as bad practice to return collection of data without dereffered execution (for example .ToList) when you're working with database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becasue EF can't translate that extension method to SQL.  Simplest way to fix it is to shift to Linq-to-Objects using `AsEnumerable()` (which is effectively what `foreach` does):

```
var model = entity.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(e => new SummaryViewModel
{
    Address = e.Address.ToOneLine(), Id = e.Id
}).ToList();
```

Unlike `ToList`, using `AsEnumerable` does not create an additional collection in memory, it just binds the Linq calls to `Enumerable` instead of `Queryable`, so the mapping is done in memory instead of in SQL.

Comment: I would be careful about this type of code. If you look at the query that EF generates for this code, it will select all of the columns from your entity instead of just the ones you are projecting. The reason is that it is projecting after it has pulled from the database since you are treating it as an IEnumerable. This can have performance implications if you do not have a covering index.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve your query, then map it.

```
var model = entity.ToList().Select(e => new SummaryViewModel
    {
        Address = e.Address.ToOneLine(), Id = e.Id
    }).ToList();
```

As it stands right now, by using deferred execution, the database is trying to interpret your ToOneLine() extension method. By resolving it immediately with ToList(), you can properly iterate over the collection on the server and map it to your model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it appears `AsEnumerable()` is the way to go.

Comment: @Blaise They do the same thing. Changing it to Enumerable and calling an extension method is going to require it to execute the query. It doesn't work on IQueryable because EF can't translate it into SQL. AsEnumerable isn't doing magic here. The only thing I don't like about this answer is the double call to ToList, which kind of smells.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
foreach (var e in entity)
```

implicitly does the same thing as `.AsEnumerable()`. Which enumerates and pulls object out of your database, when using the LINQ-expression LINQ2Entities is trying to convert it to a database expression. Ie executing it outside of the model-scope.

For a more in depth description of what `foreach` actually does, have a look at [How do foreach loops work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982/how-do-foreach-loops-work-in-c) , in reality `entity` doesn't have to be an `IEnumerable<T>`, it just has to implement a `GetEnumerator()`. Cool, huh? :)

Ie in your solution, doing

```
var model = entity.AsEnumerable().Select(e => new SummaryViewModel
    {
        Address = e.Address.ToOneLine(), Id = e.Id
    }).ToList();
```

would solve the issue.