# Why implementation of IEnumerable not require when iterate using foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I was looking into the `IEnumerable` and trying the example given in  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) link. I understand that when we iterate using `foreach` the `GetEnumerator()` method gets call because my `List` class has implemented IEnumerable (or may be I am wrong).

```
   public class List<T> : IEnumerable
    {
        private T[] _collection;
        public List(T[] inputs)
        {
            _collection = new T[inputs.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
            {
                _collection[i] = inputs[i];
            }
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
        }
        public CollectionEnum<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new CollectionEnum<T>(_collection);
        }
    }

public class CollectionEnum<T> : IEnumerator
    {
        public T[] _collection ;
        int position = -1;
        public CollectionEnum(T[] list)
        {
            _collection = list;
        }
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return (position < _collection.Length);
        }
        //implementation on Current and Reset
    }
```

Then, it is also mentioned that implementation of `IEnumerable` is not required to iterate using `foreach`. So, in the above code if I remove the implementation of `IEnumerable` the `foreach` must work. So my `List<>` class looks like

```
public class List<T>
{
    private T[] _collection;
    public List(T[] persons)
    {
        _collection = new T[persons.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < persons.Length; i++)
        {
            _collection[i] = persons[i];
        }
    }
    public CollectionEnum<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CollectionEnum<T>(_collection);
    }
}
```

And which does work. Now I did not understand how `foreach` knows my class has a method call `GetEnumerator()` which returns a `IEnumerator` type.

Comment: `foreach` knows nothing, it's just language grammar. The C# *compiler* knows how to generate CIL for the statement, and its implemented to look for a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do foreach loops work in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982/how-do-foreach-loops-work-in-c)

Comment: @Nkosi's answer corrects my previous comment - the type returned from `GetEnumerator` *doesn't* need to implement `IEnumerator`, but it *does* need to provide members that match the ones defined in that interface.

Answer (score 2):

The article you [linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_4) to provided the explanation to you already in the [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_3).

> If your collection does not implement `IEnumerable`, you must still
>   follow the iterator pattern to support this syntax by providing a
>   `GetEnumerator` method that returns an **interface, class or struct**....that contains a **Current** property, and **MoveNext** and **Reset** methods as
>   described by `IEnumerator`, but the class does not have to implement
>   `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 1):

As Nkosi mentions, in interpreting foreach, the compiler looks for a pattern originally represented in IEnumerable and IEnumerator.

Earlier versions of the C# compiler required the implementation of these interfaces.  However, with the advent of LINQ, the language and compiler have been adjusted to do more of recognizing patterns.

For instance, you can create a LINQ query around an object that has a Where method but doesn't implement IEnumerable.

Similarly, you can await any object that follows the Awaitable Pattern not just Task or Task.

Once you understand the particular methods the compiler is looking for to satisfy a pattern it becomes easier to wrap your head around why IEnumerable is not required for foreach.  Remember also that foreach is really just syntactic sugar for traversing a collection of objects.