# Unexpected Foreach behavior C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, loops, foreach

The `foreach loop` have an unexpected behavior when the condition is `true` in fact after all instruction inside `if statement`, the loop breaks. I tried to comment the if statement and all works fine (iterate all the elements into the ienumerable). Someone can explain me why?

```
var allRef = projDefinition
    .Element(msbuild + "Project")
    .Elements(msbuild + "ItemGroup")
    .Elements(msbuild + "COMReference")
    .Where(refElem => find.Any(f => refElem.FirstAttribute.Value.ToLower().Contains(f)))
    .Select(refElem => refElem);


foreach (var xElement in allRef)
{
    var name = xElement.FirstAttribute.Value;
    var dllPath = dllFiles.FirstOrDefault(dll => dll.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));

    if (dllPath != null)
    {
        var dllName = dllPath.Substring(dllPath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, dllPath.LastIndexOf('.') - dllPath.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
        xElement.Remove();
        XElement elem = new XElement(msbuild + "Reference", new XAttribute("Include", dllName));
        elem.Add(new XElement(msbuild + "HintPath", HintPath.GetHintPath(dllPath)));
        elem.Add(new XElement(msbuild + "EmbedInteropTypes", "False"));
        projDefinition.Root.Elements(msbuild + "ItemGroup").ElementAt(0).Add(elem);
    }

}

projDefinition.Save(fullProjectPath);
```

Comment: any exceptions while debugging line-by-line through the if block?

Comment: do you mean `if (dllPath != null)` messes with foreach loop? if this is your actual code then I wont believe what you said without seeing it with my own eyes.

Comment: no man, there are no exceptions.

Comment: You are modifying the source sequence inside the `foreach`, and LINQ queries use deferred execution. Add `.ToList()` at the end of `allRef` query.

Comment: My bet is `xElement.Remove();` modyfying `allRef` while still iterating through it.

Comment: so why there are any exception that tell me this? and what's exactly happen? someone please explain me. I know that LINQ use deferred execution, but I can't understand why it breaks the loop and tell me no exception.

Comment: @CRK When altering the source collection while in a foreach you risk confusing the iteration.  In your case you are removing an item in the source which can make it believe that the collection is done.  There is no exception because it doesn't realize that it did not iterate through the entire collection.

Comment: @CRK The LINQ methods check to see what the next item will be when you ask it for that next item, so if you remove a given item after you construct the query but before you ask for that item, then it won't be returned, because *at the time you asked for another item* it wasn't there.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. So why it works with a list? It don't have to have the same behavior?

Comment: You might want to look into `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to simplify getting the `dllName`.

Answer (score 5):

You're looping over `allRef` while at the same time you're removing from it with `xElement.Remove`, which messes with loop iterator.

Basicaly `foreach` creates `IEnumerator` under the hood and uses it to move from current element to next. You're disturbing it by removing element from collection while still going over it.

It will not cause exception, but your loop will cause unexpected behaviour like not going over all elements.

You may want to read [how does foreach works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398982/how-do-foreach-loops-work-in-c)

Simple solution for this kind of problem is adding `.ToList()` (as @Ivan Stoev noted in comments). It works because it creates new list so `foreach` iterator is created to that new list instead of your `allRef`. Which means that you can safely remove elements from `allRef`.

Answer (score 2):

For some more detail on how this works specifically, an `XDocument` is essentially similar to 'linked list' of nodes. Each element has a reference to its sibling and to its parent.

The various queries (like `Elements`) all use iterator blocks and are lazily evaluated. You can follow this in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,2596).

Once you call `Remove` on the current loop variable, the element is removed from the document tree. The references it had to its parent and its sibling are now both `null`. When the iterator resumes on the call to `MoveNext` as part of your `foreach` loop, there's nowhere to go; iteration complete.

As explained in the comments & other answers, a simple call to `ToList` before iterating over that will resolve the issue as it will iterate through your query and cache it in a new list. Removing nodes from the document later cannot affect the content of your list.