# Unity remove collision physical effects, but also check if there is collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a function that looks like this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Despawner")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Char")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        ScoreHandler.coinsCollected++;
    }
}
```

Basically what i want is if the coin is colliding with the player, i want the coin to be removed, but also remove the physical effects from the collision, so my if i jump to the coin from below, my character won't fall back to the ground, it just goes over it and removes it like if he would have collected it.

I also tried changing `OnCollisionEnter2D` to `OnTriggerEnter2D` but didn't get it working.

Edit: I changed to `OnTriggerEnter2D` from `OnCollisionEnter2D`. now the character goes through the coins but doesn't pick them up, like if there is no collision at all, also checked the `IsTrigger` in the Editor for the `GameObject`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a `Trigger`  which is as simple as using the OnTrigger Functions instead of the OnCollision Functions, and clicking the Trigger check box on the collider.

Comment: I talk a bit about the differences between triggers and colliders here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208857/how-to-make-my-button-change-on-collision/53209235#53209235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a Trigger, instead of a Collision and its worked.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Despawner")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Char")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        ScoreHandler.coinsCollected++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to detect the collision and ignore it. I do something similar with projectiles which will overlap and bounce off each other sometimes.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) // or OnCollisionStay2D
{
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (this.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D> ());
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
    ScoreHandler.coinsCollected++;
}
```

Comment: My character still can't jump through the coins from below:
https://gyazo.com/964163e2b4c40ea27ba254b2386ee35f
You can see it at the last second, but also the character moves on top of the coins till it gets destroyed